# Meteor & MongoDB Geospatial - bounds - $within

Tags: javascript, global-variables, meteor

In my Meteor client I have defined a map object:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  map = L.map('map_canvas').locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 21});
  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(map);
});
```

I use it as a global this way I can access it in Template.xxxx.events, Template.yyy.rendered... (Dont' know if that's the best way to do it **please your input on that**)

so until here it's all good.

Now I need to perform an a Geospatial query, which can be only done server-side:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  Meteor.publish("AllMessages", function() {
    lists._ensureIndex( { location : "2d" } );
    var bottomLeftLat = map.getBounds()._southWest.lat;
    var bottomLeftLng = map.getBounds()._southWest.lng;
    var topRightLat = map.getBounds()._northEast.lat;
    var topRightLng = map.getBounds()._northEast.lng;
    return lists.find( { "location": { "$within": { "$box": [ [bottomLeftLng, bottomLeftLat] , [topRightLng, topRightLat] ] } } } );
  });
});
```

But my app crashes and I get:

```
Exception from sub ZeJzWHdF8xQg57QtF ReferenceError: map is not defined
    at null._handler (app/server/Server.js:4:25)
    at _.extend._runHandler (app/packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:815:31)
    at _.extend._startSubscription (app/packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:714:9)
    at _.extend.protocol_handlers.sub (app/packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:520:12)
    at _.extend.processMessage.processNext (app/packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:484:43)
```

Is it a loading time thing? I need to settimeouts and wait until the map is loaded before I do my query?

**edit** Here's what I tried and doesn't work

**server**

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  Meteor.publish("AllMessages", function() {
    lists._ensureIndex( { location : "2d" } );
    return lists.find();
  });
});

Meteor.methods({
  getListsWithinBounds: function(bounds) {
    return lists.find( { "location": { "$within": { "$box": [ [bottomLeftLng, bottomLeftLat] , [topRightLng, topRightLat] ] } } } );
  }
});
```

**client**

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  map = L.map('map_canvas').locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 21});
  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(map);
    bounds = {};    
    map.on('locationfound', function(e){ 
      bounds.bottomLeftLat = map.getBounds()._southWest.lat;
      bounds.bottomLeftLng = map.getBounds()._southWest.lng;
      bounds.topRightLat = map.getBounds()._northEast.lat;
      bounds.topRightLng = map.getBounds()._northEast.lng;
      console.log(bounds);
      Meteor.call("getListsWithinBounds", bounds, function(err, result) {
        console.log('call'+result); // should log a LocalCursor pointing to the relevant lists
      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: *Even better, use a custom reactive data source. I wrote a small tutorial [here](http://blog.benmcmahen.com/post/48367809759/meteors-reactive-data-sources).*

**Old post:**

I've implemented something similar. In my server code, I have the following publish function:

```
// Publish those trails within the bounds of the map view.
Meteor.publish('trails', function(bounds){
 if (bounds && bounds.southWest && bounds.northEast) {
  return Trails.find({'coordinates': {'$within' : 
    { '$box' : [bounds.southWest, bounds.northEast] }
  }}, {
    limit: 100
  });
 }
});
```

On my client-side code, I keep a client-side only collection of mapbounds. (Basically, it's a reactive model that only ever has one document).

```
MapBounds = new Meteor.Collection(null);
```

And I have a subscription on the client that looks like this:

```
// Get trails that are located within our map bounds. 
Meteor.autorun(function () {
 Session.set('loading', true);
  Meteor.subscribe('trails', MapBounds.findOne(), function(){
   Session.set('loading', false);
  }); 
});
```

Finally, my leaflet class updates the bounds model any time the map bounds change.

```
 onViewChange: function(e){
  var bounds = this.map.getBounds()
    , boundObject = { 
        southWest: [bounds._southWest.lat, bounds._southWest.lng],
        northEast: [bounds._northEast.lat, bounds._northEast.lng] 
      };

  if (MapBounds.find().count() < 1) MapBounds.insert(boundObject);
  else MapBounds.update({}, boundObject);
 }
```

Comment: Isn't keeping a separate bounds collection a bit of an overkill? Isn;t there a way to just get dynamically the bounds without savin'em?

Comment: Keep in mind that these bounds aren't actually being _saved_. The collection is a client-side collection only, so it isn't persisted on the server. You could also use Session variables, which are reactive, or possibly make your own reactive data source. The benefit is that your subscription will always update itself when these bounds change.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `map` on the client, so that variable is not available on the server. You also won't be able to do any of that map handling on the server since Leaflet is a client-side API.

If you want to ask the server to return lists from a collection within certain bounds, you should calculate the bounds on the client and then tell the server those bounds so it can find the information for you. A good approach for this would be with a [`Meteor.method`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods).

On the server, define a method that takes bounds and returns lists within those bounds:

```
Meteor.methods({
  getListsWithinBounds: function(bounds) {
    return lists.find({location: {"$within": {"$box": [bounds.bottomLeftLng, bounds.bottomLeftLat], [bounds.topRightLng, bounds.topRightLat]}});
  }
});
```

Then on the client, call the method on the server:

```
Meteor.call("getListsWithinBounds", bounds, function(err, result) {
  console.log(result); // should log a LocalCursor pointing to the relevant lists
});
```

Comment: should the method in the server be inside a startup or a publish callback function?...

Comment: No, it should just be in the server, in neither startup or publish.

Comment: The client part throws an error - it doesn't see the bounds variable, cause I have to define that one in .Startup.. but then when I do it in .Startup I have another problem, I can't get the bounds of the map because it's not yet initialized... What a mess:(

Comment: I have a question please reply to me..
whenever the method called from client the data transferred to the client is all the details of the new result or only the difference with the previous call?

Comment: @StefanoCudini Please create a new question to ask this.